# How to block all the request sent to server if the session is expired or destroyed

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

As indicated in title, right now I have captured the event when the session is expired but the problem is now can I block all the requests which are sent to `server(Tomcat)` with or without `Spring` once the session is no longer valid.

Comment: Sorry for the poor description of problem, in fact, I want the server return a status code like 510 when the session is expired and the user still sent a request to server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write a [servlet filter](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/tutorial-java-servlet-filter-example-using-eclipse-apache-tomcat/) and check if the session is not (yet) expired.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by block all the request? You can't block the incoming request TCP connection to Tomcat unless if you start modifying your firewall to talk to your tomcat to check whether the session is valid (or not).

What you can do is to stop the user to keep going on without proper session management established. As indicated by @CristopheD, you may write servlet to prevent the request to go through, or you may redirect the request to another page (e.g. login page), etc.

Comment: When I say "block" means the request after the "session expired" should be treated by tomcat in a different way- return a specific status code for example, so that the interface will react in a appropriate way.

Comment: @ypan It means not blocking the TCP connection. It is just preventing the user to carry on with the normal request. You can just create a `Filter` and check if the session is still valid. If it is not valid anymore, you can just return a specific status code or redirect to different page.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the security for all resources to require a role, except presumably the home page and the login page, and set the target of the logout action to the home page.